Add a Multipolygon on Graphics Layer : Arcgis sdk Javascript
I am not able to add a multipolygon geometry on a graphics layer. The SDK does not give me any error nor it renders the multipolygon geometry on the map.
Any help would be appreciated.

It's hard to tell what the issue is without seeing your polygon topology or code, but this sounds like a known limitation as of ArcGIS JS SDK v 4.29 -- polygon geometries must be simple when added to graphics layers (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Polygon.html).
